# MailChimp API | Python Shell | Get the list of user activity with openDate, clickDate and user email

Tags: python, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am very beginner with Python as well as with Mailchimp API, so I desperately need your advice.

My ambition is to get the campaign report from the MailChimp that will contain the data in the format:

Email ----- email openDate ----- clicked (True/False) ----- clickDate

So far I was able to write the following code:

```html
list_campaigns = client.campaigns.all(get_all=True)


for line in list_campaigns['campaigns']:
 campaign_list_name = line['recipients']['list_name']
 campaign_list_id = line['recipients']['list_id']
 print(campaign_list_id, campaign_list_name)
```

That provides me with the list of campaign and IDs. However, campaign-based reports are giving me general information on the campaign performance (e.g. number of users opened, number of clicks), and I was unable to get anything on a granular level.

Is it ever possible and if so, what might be the algorithm for the solution?

p.s. [here's](https://github.com/charlesthk/python-mailchimp) the library I've used for Python.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of campaign_ids, the following prints the email addresses followed by a list of user activity which includes open and click timestamps:

```
from mailchimp3 import MailChimp
username = username
mykey = mykey
client = MailChimp(mc_api=mykey,mc_user=username)
for idx in campaign_ids:
    email_activity = client.reports.email_activity.all(campaign_id=idx,get_all=True)
    for email_address in email_activity['emails']:
        print(email_address['email_address']
        print(email_address['activity'])
```

Comment: got an unexpected keyword argument 'mc_api'